# Why is VSCode suggesting react-native imports for useState, useEffect, etc, when I only have react installed?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a react project that I am building with VSCode and Typescript. Whenever I edit a react component and try to autocomplete a react hook like `useState`, `useEffect`, etc., it always suggests the `react-native` equivalent. I don't have react-native installed in my package.json.

Screenshot:

[image: Note the auto-complete suggestion is react-native]

This is a recent change; it used to work just fine as recently as a couple weeks ago. I haven't made any significant changes to the project since then.

EDIT: I tracked down `@types\react-native` in my yarn.lock, which was being included by an old version of `@types\styled-components`. Updating that and `styled-components` removed the dependency on react native. Now I have another odd import, as if VS Code refuses to try the normal dependency:

[image: another non-react dependency]

EDIT: My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ESNEXT" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "ESNext" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */,
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    // "rootDir": "./src",                    /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "noEmit": true /* Do not emit outputs. */,
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
//    "isolatedModules": true /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
    "strictNullChecks": true /* Enable strict null checks. */,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true /* Enable strict checking of function types. */,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */,
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    "alwaysStrict": true /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */,

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    "paths": {
      "charts": ["charts"],
      "components": ["components"],
      "assets": ["assets"],
      "helpers": ["helpers"],
      "pages": ["pages"],
      "services": ["services"]
    },                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true, /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    "baseUrl": "src",
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Make sure that in your `tsconfig.json` file, the property `compilerOptions.jsx` is set to `react`

Comment: Thanks, but already done.

Comment: What language mode is your editor in? do you have one specific to react native that could be picking up your react files?

Comment: what do you have under **node_modules/@types**? do you have only **react** folder there or is there **react-native** also?

Comment: @KevinB Just regular Typescript, as far as I know. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @tromgy Yeah, react native is in my `@types` folder for some reason. It's not in package.json but it is in yarn.lock. And it looks like styled components has a dependency on react-native types. Why would that be, and can I prevent `@types/react-native` from appearing in my intellisense or autocomplete?

Comment: What version of styled-components do you use? I also have a project using styled-components 5.3.1 (latest) and the only dependency related to react-native I see is css-to-react-native.

Comment: I was using the 5.0.0-beta version. I've updated to the most recent for styled-components and @types/styled-components, and the dependency has gone away. Now it's got another unusual auto-complete, which I'll update in the post above. Thanks for the continued help!

Comment: You can delete `@types/react-native` to remove intellisense. As for why did it show up.. Probably pulled with a package as dependency, you'll see if it gives you an error when you delete it

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where `setTimeout` as ambiguous between the window function that returns a number and the node function that returns a Note.Timeout

I resolved this by modifying the `types` option under `compilerOptions` in my `tsconfig.js` -- if you post that file we can take a look.

The other things to check are the bottom-right of vscode has a language specification, ensure the IDE isn't targeting react native.

Last note is, for me, after modifying types it isn't uncommon for me to need to either close and reopen or `cmd-shift-p` `Reload Window` to let VS code reconstitute the intellisense cache -- might be worth a go

Comment: Added my tsconfig.json. The bottom right of VSCode shows Typescript React as its language option when I have a .tsx file open.

Comment: Restarting the window and restarting intellisense don't do anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps, by mistake, install react-native globally on your computer?

Comment: Nope. Only a handful of packages, no react-native.